# Uso de un verbo conjugado en modo subjuntivo

Tags: tiempos-verbales

Estábamos discutiendo con un amigo acerca de una frase que dijo nuestro profesor de Historia:

> (...) ellos querían que se vayan [...]

Mi amigo dice que está mal usada la palabra "vayan", y que debería usarse "fueran". ¿Cuál es la opción correcta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma *vayan* puede ser tanto imperativo como presente de subjuntivo. Por tanto, algunas frases que usen el tiempo *vayan* de forma correcta podrían ser:

> Vayan ustedes, que yo no puedo. [Imperativo formal, segunda persona del plural.]
>   No creo que ellos vayan a correr ese riesgo. [Presente de subjuntivo, tercera persona del plural.]

Pero en la frase que mencionas no se usa ni el imperativo ni el subjuntivo. Necesitas usar el subjuntivo dado que el verbo está en una oración de relativo, y la frase claramente hace referencia a un hecho pasado (*ellos querían*), por tanto el tiempo a usar sería el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo:

> Ellos querían que se fueran.

Por tanto, tu amigo tiene razón.

[[Enlace a la definición de *ir* del DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy), pulsa en "Conjugar" para ver la lista completa de tiempos verbales.]

Comment: Carlos, esta respuesta deberías haberla escrito en español como la pregunta.

Comment: @DGaleano arrea, tienes razón, [se me ha ido completamente la olla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R1SJm3g#G9ZnoXV). ¡Respuesta actualizada!

Comment: :-) No importa que se te vaya la olla mientras no _[estés en la olla](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/estar_en_la_olla)_

Comment: Creo que ya tenemos una pregunta pero no sé qué palabras usar para encontrarla.  Básicamente, si lo que querían y cuándo expresaron este deseo, es obligatorio *fueran* o *fuesen*.  Pero en el caso de que el momento de expresar se encuentre en el pasado (por eso, *querían*) pero lo que quería se encuentra en lo que, en el acto de habla, el futuro, no es censurable el uso del presente (además, cambiando el lastre temporal entre cláusulas es algo bastante común especialmente en el lenguaje oral).

Answer (score 1):

La explicación es muy sencilla. El verbo de la oración subordinada debe estar en subjuntivo, y además en el mismo tiempo que el verbo de la oración principal: "vayan" es presente de subjuntivo, mientras que "fueran" es pretérito imperfecto (pasado).

Si el verbo principal estuviese en presente, entonces usaríamos "vayan":

"Ellos quieren que se vayan"

Pero si hablas de un hecho pasado, no puedes usar el verbo de la oración subordinada en presente, por tanto sería:

"Ellos querían que se fueran"

De todas formas, por echar un capote a tu profe de Historia, en el lenguaje oral todos cometemos errores ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"Que se fueran" es más natural, aún cuando el irse va a suceder en el futuro:

> Mis tíos están de visita de Guadalajara.  Cada quien tiene su opinión sobre cuándo deben regresar a casa, porque dejaron a la abuelita solita allá.  Mis papás querían que se fueran el lunes, pero mi hermana propuso ir a quedarse con la abuelita un par de días para que mis tíos se puedan quedar un poquito más tiempo con nosotros.